# DllImport, how to check if the DLL is loaded?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am doing a P/Invoke, and I am using the following method

```
[DllImport("Authz.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern BOOL AuthzFreeContext(
        IntPtr phAuthzResourceManager);
```

even though its working, how is it guaranteed that `Authz.dll` is always loaded into my code. Suppose my `dll` is some `XXX.dll` how should I check in general if that dll is loaded or not before using that, so that I don't get a method not found exception.

Comment: You can P/Invoke on loadlibrary and see if that succeeds? http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.loadlibrary

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`Marshal.PrelinkAll(Type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.prelinkall)

or

[`Marshal.Prelink(MethodInfo)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.prelink)

Sadly, the documentation fails to mention any exceptions being thrown if the DLL is not found. I have just verified via a simple app that it is indeed a `DllNotFoundException` being thrown.

Comment: What does happen if Prelink does fail? According to the docs there is no error code or exception thrown when something could not be resolved.

Comment: @AloisKraus: `DllNotFoundException` IIRC (or some `IOException`).

Comment: @AloisKraus: Easy enough to test ;p

Comment: It can throw EntryPointNotFoundException when method doesn't exist. This can happen for DLL with different version.

Comment: Also, you can get a BadImageFormatException if your try to load a corrupted DLL (happened to me).